# PC stuck on upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade

My PC got stuck while upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04. It has been stuck on 'Configuring libsmbclient (amd64)' from the last 4 hours & in the terminal part its showing 'Setting up udisks2 (2.1.7-1ubuntu1)'. I am able to hover the mouse, but nothing else seems to be working, neither the keyboard nor the mouse clicks. What should be the best thing to do at this moment?

Answer (score 0):

Never do a "dirty upgrade" (upgrading the OS version over the old one using the update manager or command line), always do a fresh install. 90% of the time, dirty upgrades screw something up. Sometimes minor, usually major. Sometimes I get lazy and try a dirty upgrade, hoping they fixed this, I always end up backing up my data, wiping my drive and doing a fresh installing of the  new version.

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: Backup your data, download 16.04, burn it to a DVD or a USB drive, boot from that, erase your hard drive, install 16.04 fresh.